# how to make IPJSUA become a .IPA file?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, xcode4.3

I just compile the IPJSUA and build using xCode 4.3.2, and also run on simulator. But still can't call/send IM. 
I'm thinking about limitation for simulator, now I want to deploy into .IPA file and test it using my phone. But I got an error.

If I'm using iPhone Developer Certificate, I got a lot of error like this pic.

[image]
If I'm using iPhone Distribution Certificates, I got a error message like this.

> No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates

Anybody ever try how to make IPJSUA into .IPA files? 
What different between iPhone Developer Certificate and iPhone Distribution Certificate?

Here is the picture, I already linked the library, the architectures, and the search path. 
[image]

I already can make the .IPA file, but still can't make a call or send IM. can you make a call with IPJSUA using your devices/simulator?
thanks.

**UPDATE:** Already can call/send IM/add buddy. I will Refer to the new question that I will answer by myself. The step by step of using PJSIP on xCode. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just testing it on your own phone, and your phone is registered in the developer portal then there is no need to generate a .IPA file.  You can just plug your device into the computer and build it directly onto the device. If however you want to distribute to multiple devices that aren't registered yet(such as friend's devices), i would suggest looking into testflight which simplifies this process, and gives a step by step instruction [here](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/494413-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4-3-) on how to  create and upload your IPA.

Comment: however, i tried it already. plug my device and build it directly. but still failed. I the error that i posted yesterday. but, if i'm using simulator, there are no error.

Answer (score 1):

It took me days to get ipjsua running on devices. A couple things I ran into:

Are you linking to all the proper binaries? There's about 20 or so you need to link to, you can check their ipjsua sample app for reference.

Did you add the armv7 and armv6 architectures in your build settings? We had to add both (this was probably back in September of last year when we were building it, for reference)

Are your Library Search Paths and Header Search Paths in build settings correct? For headers we have pjsip/include, pjlib/include, pjlib-util/include, pjnath/include, and pjmedia/include. For Library paths we have all the same (with /lib instead of /include of course)